# Can the "impossible" verdict to the $V_\text{ave} = 2V_1$ question be overturned using relativity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, special-relativity, velocity, inertial-frames

On Veritasium, Derek Muller [asked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HgCXdNhVC1Q&t=2m19s) and [answered](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=72DCj3BztG4&t=2m44s) if you could run two laps round a track at $V_1$ (for lap one) and $V_2$ (for lap two) such that your average speed $V_{ave}$ over both laps would be equal to $2V_1$

This would mean:
$$ \frac{2s}{t_1} = \frac{2s}{t_1+t_2} $$
$$ \therefore t_2 = 0 \, ,$$

hence the "impossible" conclusion.

However, using relativistic velocities and the start-finish line on the track (or some other fixed point on Earth, moving through space) as a reference point, could it be possible to make $V_\text{ave} = 2V_1$?

My own efforts to answer this have failed very early in the process. I can see from the [velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) that both points must be moving (but relative to what, I have no idea) otherwise the bottom of the equation goes to $1$ and the total is $v + u'$ as in the normal way of doing it. I think that this formula would need to be re-arranged so that you get a way of adding times (rather than velocities), but my maths isn't strong enough to know how to do this. Also I'm not sure if you can substitute $v=\frac{s}{t}$ directly into this equation, since the $t$ component might have special rules in this context (I'm thinking *time* is what makes the velocities relativistic, and the distances are considered fixed).

Comment: How do you think the relativistic addition of velocities would apply? Please show your attempt to answer your own question.

Comment: @sammygerbil well I know that relative velocity is slightly less than $V_1+V_2$ (all the way up to $c+c=c$), so I thought it might be possible to make the average velocity equal $2V_1$ using this. My own attempt to answer this was a non-starter, I looked at the [velocity addition formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula) but my maths isn't strong enough to understand any of it beyond the initial $u=$... part, and my physics isn't strong enough to know how to treat the Newtonian $v=s/t$ formula when using it in a relativity formula (or even if you can do this at all).

Comment: What "relative velocity" are you referring to? It is not your mathematical ability which is the difficulty here. The difficulty is, how does this formula enter the problem? The relativity formula gives you the velocity of B relative to A if the velocities of A and B are known in some other frame of reference. In this case we don't have two travellers A and B. We only have one traveller. What is A? What is B?

Comment: Please can you point out the relevant times in the videos, to save users having to watch the whole video to find the problem addressed by your question.

Comment: @sammygerbil I've edited the time indexes into the video links. A is a fixed point on Earth (possibly the start/finish line of the track). B is the runner. They are both moving points when observed from some place not on Earth, or maybe even as observed by another runner traveling at a different speed. I think there could be a reference point where $V_{ave}$ appears to equal $2V_1$, but I don't know how to find it, or the required velocities. Or I could be totally wrong, which would also be a valid answer to my question.

Comment: In any given frame, the calculation (and the conclusion that $t_2=0$ is just as you've given it.  Relativity doesn't change a thing.  It seems to me that there's no question here.

Answer (score 3):

#### Yes, it can

If you analyze it from the reference frame of the runner, then during the first lap their velocity is $v_1=0$, because they are at rest w.r.t. themselves, and during the second lap their velocity is $v_2=0$, for the same reasons, so their average velocity is
$$
v_\mathrm{avg}=0=2v_1.
$$
You don't like it? Then you can analyze things in the reference frame of the track, in which

#### No, it can't

In the reference frame of the track, which is the one that really matters, relativity does not affect the argument at all. The argument as seen from the track only talks about what distances were covered (by track rulers) in what time (by track clocks) and it's only in the final tally that you begin to talk about velocities. The argument is best distilled as

> a trajectory cannot cover distance $2s$ in time $t$ if it has already covered a distance $s$ in time $t$, because it is out of time.

None of that changes if you change to relativistic dynamics.

---

You could then ask how this looks like from some arbitrary frame moving at velocity $u$. Frankly, I think that that isn't all that interesting, and that it breaks away from what the question was asking, but in any case, no matter how you see it, the statement above remains true - the runner is out of time, no matter what reference frame is doing the analysis.

Answer (score 2):

When we invoke relativity, we have to ask: is whose time are we talking about?

Let's say there are two tracks that are both of the same length $s$, one after the other. The runner would run at $V_{1}$ for the first track and he'll run at $V_{2}$ for the second track.

Let's also say there is a referee moving along the tracks at a speed $U$.
Let's use the referee's time in this case. From the referee's frame, you have to transform a couple of things. First of all, you have to use the velocity addition formulas to adjust the runner's speed, and the tracks would have a different length by Lorentz contraction from the referee's point of view.

This gives 
$$ s' = s\sqrt{1-\frac{U^{2}}{c^{2}}},\quad V_{1}' = \frac{V_{1}+U}{1+\tfrac{V_{1}U}{c^{2}}}, \quad\text{and}\quad V_{2}' = \frac{V_{2}+U}{1+\tfrac{V_{2}U}{c^{2}}}. $$

Here's the problem: now that we've transformed everything, we got back a situation that is identical to the one we started with. The tracks have length $s'$, and the runner runs at speeds $V_{1}',V_{2}'$. If we think about the referee's time, then the situation is not changed. We still have $V'_{1} = s'/t'_{1}$ and $V'_{2} = s'/t'_{2}$ so then $V'_{\text{avg}} = 2V'_{1}$ implies

$$ \frac{V'_{1}t'_{1} + V'_{2}t'_{2}}{t'_{1} + t'_{2}} = 2V'_{1} \implies \frac{2s'}{t'_{1}+t'_{2}} = \frac{2s'}{t'_{1}}. $$

Therefore, I'd say this can't happen in any single reference frame. I'd be interested to see what others think.

---

It'd be more interesting to see what would happen if you used the runner's times in this case. I've tried to look at this, but it become algebraically difficult so far.

Comment: Interesting.. I hadn't considered that the distance would also change. But if the referee 'knows' the actual distance from a prior measurement and uses the times he observes to calculate velocities, does that change things?

Comment: Hmm. I don't think it would (the terminology is "proper distance" or "rest length"), because you're just rescaling distance. However, there is something I did want to analyze that might be interesting: what happens if the runner himself times the runs. This would not be a trivial rescaling, because he changes speed between the two tracks.

Comment: ->any single *inertial* reference frame ;) But good answer. Emilio Pisanty covers what happens in the runner's frame, which is quite boring.

Comment: Ohh, I see. The possibility I had in mind was for the runner to use his time, but measure his speed with respect to the tracks so that $V_{1},V_{2}\ne 0$. I think the answer will still be no, but the case will not be trivial.